# Python, не могу сделать абзацы с отступами при создании docx

Tags: python

Делаю парсинг сайта и данные надо записать в формат Docx. Но все записывается сплошняком, без отступов. Код примерно такой:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
URL_TEMPLATE = "https://tl.rulate.ru/book/422/215679/ready_new"
r = requests.get(URL_TEMPLATE)
soup = bs(r.text, "html.parser")
divs = soup.find('div', class_='chapter').find_all('p')
f = open('text.docx', 'w', encoding='utf-16')
for p in divs:
    vartext = p.text + "\n"
    print(vartext)
    f.write(vartext)
f.close()
```

Текст с сайта идет по абзацам, но код записывается на последнее место игнорируя отступы. Помогите решить.

Comment: Воспользуйтесь библиотекой python-docx.
Решение похожей [проблемы](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30584681/how-to-properly-indent-with-python-docx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если не принципиально в `.docx` сохранять, то лучше в `.txt`
Если всё же важно сохранять в `.docx`, то нужно воспользоваться библиотекой  [python-docx](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)
Также для переноса строки в Windows нужно использовать `\r\n`
Для Linux только `\n`